# Oracle Express Synchronization from Another Orable Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, linked-server, data-synchronization

I have a Oracle 10g database currently in a server.

I will create a web which may have massive requests to get data from the Oracle 10g. So, to prevent degrade the Oracle 10g database and server performance, I would like to setup an Oracle Express 11g to another server, periodically (say 15 minutes) get the data from Oracle 10g to Oracle Express 11g.

Finally the web will just get the data from the new server. And the only loading to the Oracle 10g is the data synchronization. There are just 2 tables in Oracle 10g need to sync.

My question is how can I set up the data synchronization?

For example, can I set up linked server, and set materialized view with refresh period between 2 oracles.

I am new to Oracle, welcome any useful reference materials and idea.

Comment: Can you?  Sure.  Assuming the total amount of data we're talking about is less than 11 GB.  If your goal is to use the express edition database to serve a "massive" number of web requests, that would seem quite problematic.  The express edition is limited to 1 CPU core.

Comment: Yes, this maybe one of the limitations. But I want to know the way to set up data synchronization despite limitations, i.e. database to database. Batch job program is not preferred.

Comment: As I said, can you?  Sure.  There is plenty of documentation out there for how to create database links, how to create materialized views, how to create materialized view logs on the source, how to create refresh groups, etc.  As it sits, then, your question is overly broad since each of those items is a chapter in a manual at least.  But, like I said, it won't work if your goal is to offload the reporting queries.